# Google Maps not initializing in Angular ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, google-maps

I have google maps set up for multiple components at once, and to display them all on the same page I had to give them all unique dynamic ID's, and to do that I need to put the initialization in `ngAfterViewInit()` I believe. So I did that but now my map doesn't show. Here's what I have...

in my component:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.randId = this.randomIdGenerator(); <-- Generates an ID for the elements
    this.mapId = 'map-'+this.randId;
    this.pacId = 'pac-input-'+this.randId;
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapId), this.mapConfig);
    this.input = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(this.pacId);
    this.map.set("mapTypeId", 'roadmap');
    this.searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(this.input);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(this.input);
    this.searchBox.addListener('places_changed', () => {
        this.placesChanged(this.searchBox.getPlaces()[0]);
    }); 
  }
```

template:

```
<md-card>
    <input
      style="color:black"
      id="{{pacId}}"
      name='address'
      class="mapControls"
      type="text"
      value=""
      placeholder="Enter Address">
    <div id="{{mapId}}"></div>
</md-card>
```

The id's are being assigned to the elements, however the map just doesn't show up. I'm not getting any errors either... It appears the code IS finding the elements. So that's good. But after it's findiong the elements the map doesn't open.

Comment: `id="{{pacId}}"` -> `id="pacId"`

Comment: same problem. The map isn't loading. It was loading when I put it in `ngOnInit` but that didn't work because the template id's are empty at that moment

Comment: And you did the same for `mapId`?

Comment: They're variables so should be in {{}} that part works, if I inspect them they do have the proper id's. I added a bit of code to show that part.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't paying much attention. It's either [id]="mapId" OR id={{mapId}}. In your DOM they might have the right id with the latter method, but in order for your component to be updated you need to use `[id]`

Comment: Same results :S

Answer (score 0):

So this fixed it:

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px" [id]="mapId"></div>
```

I guess the div was being created at a 0px size initially, and not growing when we added the map to it.